# Finding Intensity of light incident on a photodiode

Tags: energy, visible-light

Given a halogen lamp(9500lumen,500W) at a distance d from a photodiode. How can I find the intensity of light incident on the photodiode?

Comment: If there are no optical elements involved,the light of your lamp is emitted into all directions (spherical symmetry). With that you can calculate the fraction of intensity of a given sphere (use your radius $d$), which falls onto a given area (the active area of your photodiode). This only holds true, if there are no optical elements (lenses, mirrors) involved. Keep in mind, these could also be integrated in your halogen lamp's packaging.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of subtle considerations involved in precise measurements and calculations of **luminous intensity**.  This article gives an taste of the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela

If what you want is an answer in watts per square meter, you are going to have to either settle for an estimate based on typical properties of halogen bulbs or get ready to take a lot of your own measurements of the lightbulb.

It matters what range of frequencies of light you want to include in your intensity and which frequencies you want to exclude (over what range is your photodiode how sensitive?).

The rating of 9500 Lumens means that the lightbulb "seems similarly bright to the human eye" to a source emitting (some wattage that you can calculate from 9500 lumens using the article above) watts of light at a frequency of 540,000,000,000,000 Hz.  This does not allow you to know what intensity your photodiode will measure unless you also have:

1. The sensitivity spectrum for a "standard" human eye
2. The senstivity spectrum of your photodiode
3. the emission spectrum of your lightbulb

No matter what method you use to calculate haw many watts of relevent light the bulb is producing, you will then divide this wattage by 4*pi*d^2 (the surface area of the sphere centered on the bulb and passing through the photodiode) to get the intensity at the photodiode.